# Integral of scaled function

Tags: calculus

I am trying to determine what happens to the integral of a function when you scale the independent variable.

How does the integral of $f(x)$ differ from the integral of $f(ax)$? I found a similar answer but it simply stated that it is easy to show with substitution, without showing it.

Comment: Think about it. Let $ u = ax \ldots$

Comment: This may seem obvious to you, but I see how substitution shows this is 1/a * integral(f(u)du) . However, what I am trying to do is show that 1/a * integral(f(x)dx) = integral(f(ax)dx). Is it sufficient to just say it was shown by substitution?

Comment: Yes. Because that's all it is, a change of variables.